# Error updating Google Play Services from 6.5.87 to 7.5.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I'm trying to update the google play services lib from 6.5.87 to 7.5.0 but after change the android version at the build.gradle:

[image: build.gradle import at 6.5.87]

I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error after update to 7.5.0]

I had read that this error is related to appcompat but I'm not using or including this lib.

This is my complete build.gradle: 
    import java.util.regex.Pattern

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    // Configuration for Fabric
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric' // Fabric Gradle plugin, always after Android plugin

dependencies {
    // 'jar' files in '/libs' folder
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'

    // Fabric
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.+@aar') {
    transitive = true;
    }
}
repositories {
mavenCentral()

// Configuration for Fabric
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is u have changed Project label Gradle instead of App label.
Solution:
Put compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87' 
is App Label Gradel file put `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` as well.

Similarly 
in Project label Gradle file put

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Example:
**app Gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appifiedtech.androidgoogleplusapi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

}
```

**Project Label Gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the classpath, the plugin and update the google-play-services version and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: my build.gradle of project level and app level is the same build.gradle.